# R Self Organising Subset

Tags: r

I have a matrix with a hundred rows.
Is there a way to obtain a subset of ten rows which are most similar to the first row.

```
res2 <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=10, nrow=100)

set1 <- subset(res2, res2 >condition1)
set1[with(set1, order(condition)), ]
set2 <- head(set1,10)
```

Comment: How do you define most similar?

Comment: Having the closest similar pattern.

Comment: I think the question is interesting and I'm sure others may too but you haven't provided much info (as Christoph pointed out) and no reproducible example (a data set at the very least).  Levenshtein comes to mind as a possible approach (maybe with `agrep`)

Comment: I will try to post an example and a possible starting solution that can be improved on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

Generate data:

```
set.seed(101)
res2 <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=10, nrow=100)
```

Calculate the distance matrix.  This is very inefficient because we're computing *all* of the pairwise distances, but it's efficiently coded and easy to use and you have lots of choices of distance metric (see `?dist`, look for `method`).  For this size problem it's very quick.

```
dd <- dist(res2)
rr <- rank(as.matrix(dd)[1,])
```

You'll notice that the rank of the first element of the first row (which is the distance between row 1 and itself) is 1, and its value (`as.matrix(dd)[1,1]`) is zero. So all we need now are the rows with the next ten smallest distances ...

```
res2[rr>1 & rr<=11,]
```

Comment: That's excellent! Thank you very much for your beautiful solution.